# Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to create a script to export the conditional policies in Microsoft Exchange.

This is the script I've got:

```
#Export your Conditional Access policies to a JSON file for backup.
$Parameters = @{
ClientID = 'xx'
ClientSecret = 'xx'
FilePath = 'my folder'
}

Export-DCConditionalAccessPolicyDesign @Parameters
```

Note: Client ID and Secret are correctly written.

Then a pop up asking for credentials show, I put in the credentials, the server asks for authorization, I grant access and the following shows up:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR0mm.png)

After some research, it looks to be an authentication issue, but I can't seem to get a solution.

I'd appreciate any help.

I have tried some credentials validators unsuccessfully.

Comment: You are failing Microsoft Graph Authentication which is OAUTH2.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts?force_isolation=true

Comment: Hey Mr. jdweng, I have had a look at this, I tried adding Powershell as an app with permissions but lokks nt to be possible to do. Again, this is a script executed directly form there is there's not third party app that needs permission. Any other suggestion that could help?

Comment: Some servers prevent automation and only allow manual connections.  But this is not possible in all cases because you are making a HTTP Connection  which contains three parts 1) URI 2) Header 3) Body.  There is not difference between a manual browser connection and an automated connection like a Invoke-RestMethod.  You can prevent more than one connection from the same source, and you can add timers to prevent a connection from the same source IP (or account) to occur to often.  But a HTTP connection is always the same format.  So it is always possible to make the connection.

Comment: It is not simple.  Along with an HTTP connection there is windows credentials that have to be passed.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/credentials-processes-in-windows-authentication or AUTH2 authentication : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow